'CSRF token mismatch' error in React and Laravel Project
I have CSRF token mismatch error only for the login POST request.
My project has React v18.2.0 as frontend (hosted on hostinger website) and Laravel v10.10 as backend (hosted on hostinger vps) Entering the frontend and backend url separately works fine. GET requests correctly get the data to load on my homepage
The error
{
"data": {
    "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
    "file": "/home/user/htdocs/backend-domain/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php",
    "line": 492,
    "trace": [...]
},
"status": 419,
"statusText": "",
"headers": {
    "cache-control": "private, must-revalidate",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "expires": "-1",
    "pragma": "no-cache"
},
"config": {
    "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
        "xhr",
        "http"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
    "baseURL": "https://srv545719.hstgr.cloud/",
    "withCredentials": true,
    "withXSRFToken": true,
    "method": "post",
    "url": "/login",
    "data": "{\"email\":\"admin@correo.com\",\"password\":\"adminpassword\"}"
},
"request": {}

}
When I try to login I get the error 419 "CSRF token mismatch."
This is how I have my backend configured
.env
APP_URL=https://backend-domain
FRONTEND_URL=https://frontend-domain
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_COOKIE=frontend-domain
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=frontend-domain,backend-domain
SESSION_DOMAIN=frontend-domain

config/cors.php
'paths' => ['*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['https://frontend-domain', 'https://backend-domain'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,

config/session.php
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => 'none',
    'partitioned' => false,

config/sanctum.php
  'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS')),
    'guard' => ['web'],
    'expiration' => null,
    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

kernel.php
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
             \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, 
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LogCookies::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LogCookies::class,
        ],
    ];

on the frontend
AuthContext.jsx
  const csrf = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching CSRF token:", error);
    }
  };

  function getCsrfToken() {
    const match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+)'));
    return match ? match[2] : null;
  }
  

  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://backend-domain',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
    withCredentials: true
  });

  const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    await csrf();
    try {
      const csrfToken = getCsrfToken();
      const response = await axiosInstance.post(
        "/login",
        { email, password },
        {
          headers: {
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken, 
          },
        }
      );
      navigate("/admin/");
      await getUser();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login:", error);
      if (error.response.status === 422) {
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
      } else if (error.response.status === 403) {
        console.error("Error:", error.response.data.message);
      }
    }
  };
  

If I check the cookies saved using the devtools, I don't have any cookies, I guess this is part of the error.
It worked correctly on localhost

This question is similar to: Why do I get error "CSRF token mismatch". React 18 SPA with Laravel 10 API. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73536569/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-axios-post-request

When you do a POST request, you'll have to create one request for the CSRF token and then use it with your POST request. Please see Laravel Docs
EDIT
There is boilerplate from Laravel to work with NextJS and Laravel Sanctum. Please refer to it.
